# show $\ell^p$ is dense in $\ell^q$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I am trying to show $\ell^p$ is dense in $\ell^q$,  where p< q so  i need to  show  that any $\epsilon > 0$  for any $(x_i)\in\ell^q$ there is $(y_i) \in \ell^p$  such that $d((x_i),(y_i)) < \epsilon$.
 Let be $(x_i) \in l^q$ and  $\epsilon$ be orbitrary. We know $\sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_i|^q <\infty$
  this means $\exists$ n such that $\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty |x_i|^q < {(\epsilon)^p \over 2^p}$ .

Consider $y=(y_1,y_2, . . .,y_n,0,0,. . .)$ and let  $(y_i) \in \ell^p$ and each $y_i$ is rational.
Since the rationals are dense in $\Bbb{R}$ , for each $x_i$ there is rational $y_i$ close to it. Hence we can find a $y \in \ell^p$ satisfying

$\sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_i-y_i|^q< {\epsilon^p\over 2^p}$.
It follows that $d(x,y)=(\sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_i-y_i|^q)^{1\over p} < (\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i-y_i|^q + \sum_{i=n+1}^\infty |x_i|^q)^{1\over p} < \epsilon$

Is it true? If it is not true, can you show me the way to do it please? Thank you for your help.

Comment: This essentially works, but there's no need to go to the rationals.  You can just take $y_i = x_i$ for $1 \le i \le n$.

Comment: You are essentially showing that the set of finite sequences (that is, zero after some index) is dense in $l_p$, for any $p< \infty$.

Comment: do you mean is it wrong ?  i want to show $\ell^p$  is dense in $\ell^q $.

Answer (score 4):

As [Nate Eldredge](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1207612/show-ellp-is-dense-in-ellq#comment2456706_1207612) and [copper.hat](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1207612/show-ellp-is-dense-in-ellq#comment2456726_1207612) said: the proof works, but there's no need to go to the rationals.  You can just take $y_i = x_i$ for $1 \le i \le n$.

The idea of proof is to show that sequences with finitely many nonzero elements are dense in $\ell^q$. This is sufficient  for conclusion, because such sequences are contained in every $\ell^p$.